# Advice - XA, JTA, and JMS - Use XA to read from JMS and write to DB in transaction

Tags: java, transactions, jms, jta, xa

At work I've been asked to read from a JMS queue (actually, something proprietary with a similar interface) and write to a database within the same transaction.  For example, if the database insert fails, I should roll back the read from the queue.

I'm not very experienced with Java and don't have a great deal of knowledge about XA, JTA, or JMS.  I'm trying to read up on everything so that I understand the technologies well enough to achieve my goal.

Anyway, I'm a little confused about how these things relate to each other.

1. I believe an XA driver is used to communicate with the database to manage distributed transactions - but does the XA driver work with the message queue as well?
2. Do I use the JTA interface to manage the XA functionality which lets me run a transaction between the database and the queue, or do I have to use some XA API directly?
3. Does anyone know a location where I can find code samples that do transactions between two components (not necessarily a JMS queue and a database, but anything that uses XA to manage a transaction over multiple participants)?

Sorry if this is  a little broad, I'm just looking for enough pointers so that I can be pointed in the right direction and know what to read.

Comment: Is the application running inside Java EE container?

Comment: At this point, I'm just trying to learn the concepts.  So, it can be if that makes the learning experience easier.

Comment: Distributed transactions are tremendously easier to handle using a Java EE container. The container will handle the transactions for you, if you just create a container managed message driven bean with transaction attribute set to required.